# Rectangular corners overlapping a View in a RecyclerView even though both views have rounded XML backgrounds

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, drawable, rounded-corners

I implemented a RecyclerView with rounded corners. For the background of my item in the RecyclerView and the background of my Recyclerview I used this XML:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
         android:color="@color/colour"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

If I initialise the RecyclerView with with  no items in it, the RecyclerView has rounded corners and it looks like this:

[image]

Then, if I initialise the RecyclerView with 1 item in it, I get a grey coloured rectangular cornered overlap, which looks like this [image]

But when I click on the item, which triggers the method    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner_drawable) to be called on the item, after that method is called the grey corners are gone and the item looks like this: [image]

**The problem in a nutshell:** Why are these grey rectangular corners appearing over the item when the background XML has rounded corners ? And why do these grey rectangular overlapping corners disappear when I set the same background using a click stimulus ?

Let me know if you need any more code.

Thanks in advance